# Is burg compatible with 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, bootloader, burg, testing

Has anybody tested burg on natty? Is it safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burg on Natty works correctly via a [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39049/burg-themes-not-working/39151#39151).

As with all PPAs - these must be used with care.  In this case - especially so - since incorrect installation could prevent you booting.  **Have a good backup (for example - with clonezilla) before you install**.

**Linked Questions:**

1. [How do I install burg themes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50646/how-do-i-install-burg-themes/50647#50647)
2. [Burg themes not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39049/burg-themes-not-working/39151#39151)

Answer (score 7):

I am using Burg with Natty with no issues so far. The general [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/burg/wiki/InstallUbuntu) to install it work Ok. Remember to run `sudo burg-install /dev/sda`(or your device in place of /dev/sda

Comment: the ppa is for maverick! should I continue with the same?

Comment: Just did this, yeah continue with maverick, it works fine.

Comment: @Hailwood @Papiux will the maverick ppa be supported in the future versions?

Comment: Even if its not its no big deal to change to ppa.

Comment: Sorry about my late answer, thanks @Hailwood for that. I'm sure they'll update for Natty but no problem to use it for now.