# Burg themes not working

Tags: 11.04, burg

As soon as I updated to Natty my BURG stopped working. After a little tweaking here and there I somehow managed to get BURG install. So during the boot menu I do see the BURG menu but without the themes. Also none of the shortcuts to change resolution etc work. I have even tried using Burg Manager. Fail. 
Please help. This is urgent.

Comment: Why is it urgent? By the way BURG may not have been updated to work comfortably with Ubuntu 11.04, so you may have to be patient.

Comment: I updated to Natty, too, and BURG works as usual (it was installed in 10.10). No need in another PPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SourcesList.eu](http://www.sourceslist.eu/burg-2/new-burg-repository-for-kubuntu-natty-narwhal-11-04/) today have reported that there is now a Burg PPA.

**Before I continue - Remember BURG changes your Boot Loader.  Getting this wrong will stop Ubuntu from booting!**

I've reproduced the relevant part of the article below to complete the answer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
```

Then if you want to install burg execute:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install

sudo apt-get install burg burg-common burg-emu burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common
```

Then (supposing that you wannt to install burg into MBR relative to hard disk named sda) execute:

```
sudo burg-install /dev/sda && sudo update-burg
```

Now you can use burg-manager to install new themes and to configure it.