# How do I install burg themes?

Tags: installation, themes, burg

I want to install some [themes for burg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50643/what-burg-themes-are-available), how do I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install a BURG theme

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Browse to the downloaded archive file and double click - Extract the archive to /boot/burg/themes.

If there is an icon folder inside the archive, then extract the icon files to the folder /boot/burg/themes/icons

Update burg by

```
sudo update-burg
```

[source](http://abhizweblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-install-burg-themes.html)